# Issues in Edge browser after using MSAL lib for authentication

Tags: angular, azure, browser, microsoft-edge, azure-ad-msal

Facing problem to login into the application as the application goes into looping state trying to log into the application. This issue only happens on the normal window of MS Edge and the app works fine in private window of the Edge browser. We are only permitted to use MS Edge browser for Apps that we created .Application supposed to be run only on MS Edge Browser . It seems everything working as expected in Chrome and Mozila Browser .
The development team does not face the issue in any browser. So, it is unable to reproduce it in dev side to debug the issue.
Details of the Lib used-
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.12.0",

Below are the screenshot –

1. App tries to login again and again which leads it to go in loop.

[MS Edge Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpQHT.png)
The network tab keeps on refreshing every second trying to login.
The issue only happens on the client organization machine they use.
Somehow the library has been blocked by the Edge settings or configs which is causing the issue.

We are expecting our Angular MSAL Authenticated apps should be working in MS Edge Browser in Normal window . User Should be able to login through MS Edge Browser normal Window .

Answer (score 0):

It is known issue on Microsoft Edge browsers (MSAL.js) and the Edge team works on a resolution.
From the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-js-known-issues-ie-edge-browsers), you could try the possible workarounds check if it helps unblock you.
**First.**
Fixes for the authentication redirect loop issues have been released in [MSAL.js 0.2.3](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/releases). Enable the flag `storeAuthStateInCookie` in the MSAL.js config to take advantage of this fix. By default this flag is set to false.
When the `storeAuthStateInCookie` flag is enabled, MSAL.js uses the browser cookies to store the request state required for validation of the auth flows.
**Second.**
1.As a first step to get around these issues, ensure that the application domain and any other sites involved in the redirects of the authentication flow are added as trusted sites in the security settings of the browser. This ensures the redirects belong to the same security zone. To do so, follow these steps:

- Open Internet Explorer and click on the settings (gear icon) in the top-right corner
- Select Internet Options
  Select the Security tab
- Under the Trusted Sites option, click on the sites button and add the URLs in the dialog box that opens.

2.As mentioned before, since only the session storage is cleared during the regular navigation, you may configure MSAL.js to use the local storage instead. This can be set as the `cacheLocation` config parameter while initializing MSAL.